# Retrieving Vulnerabilities Associated with a Specific Scan in Nexpose / InsightVM via API

Tags: security, scanning, rapid7, nexpose

I am working with the Nexpose/InsightVM API and facing a challenge in retrieving vulnerabilities specific to a scan.

Here's what I've done so far:

I have the Site ID and Scan ID.
Using the above IDs, I'm able to fetch the associated Asset ID.
I can retrieve vulnerabilities linked to an asset.
However, the issue is that one asset can be part of multiple scans, so when I fetch vulnerabilities for the asset, I get results from all the scans it's been a part of. My goal is to isolate and retrieve vulnerabilities specific to a particular scan.

Does anyone know how to achieve this using the Nexpose/InsightVM API? Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!